# I'm curious of the implementation of std::getline()

Tags: c++, file, std, ifstream, getline

I'm reading a .txt file with using `std::getline`.
I coded like this, and I became so much curious of the return value of `std::getline()`.

(`file` is an `ifstream` variable.)

```
while(!file.eof())
{
    string line;
    getline(file, line);
    cout<<line<<endl;
}
```

So, what I want to know is why `getline` can get all lines in the file.
Does `getline` have an iterator?
I want to know how it's file cursor moves.

Comment: see this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/  everything is there.

Comment: to know what a method does you should read the documentation, to know how it does it, you need to look at the source, not sure what else you expected as an answer....

Comment: `getline` doesn't have a "file position", but `ifstream` has.

Comment: std::getline() always reads just one line of text. Your code fragment will print the whole file contents because of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question for the second time I think i know what the question is about (..maybe...)

`getline` doesnt know where you are in the file, thats the streams job. `getline` just reads from the current position until it encouters the delimiter. `getline` does not need to keep track of the current position in the file, because that bookkeeping is done by the `ifstream`.